# AWS ECS via Python, looking for exit status (and maybe even stdout)

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ecs

Folks;

We're using AWS Glue to drive a number of ETL type tasks ... one of which needs to be run in a Container because of some legacy POSIX dependencies.  For this, I have a short Python / boto3 script to run_task() from Glue just so that we can centrally manage all workflows.

I can run my ECS task (has to be EC2, not Fargate), no problem.  And FYI, I am using waiters to watch for provisioning then running.  My Glue hosted stub exits only after the ECS task completes.

But I cannot figure-out how to get the exit status of the run within the Container.  A bonus would be to also to have the ability to capture stdour/stderr from ECS via this Python stub.

Looks like I / we could query CloudWatch via boto3 after the ECS task completes, but this seems like a cumbersome approach (and I don't want to do this because the API rate limits for 'describe log') ...

I am hoping for pointers to where I may have a gap in understanding, or confirmation that this cannot be done today.

Comment: `describe-tasks` on a finished task should have an exit code value for each container in the task. For the stdout/stderr, I would definitely design an alternate method of communication, such as having the task write to a SQS queue.